# Javascript calling webservice error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to call a simple web service and send an email address as a parameter, and i'm getting this error saying "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/IsPreUsedEmail'".

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Client side:

```
function GetIsPreUsedEmail(sEmail) 
{
    var Url = "http://localhost:52476/MyShul/Services/GetData.asmx/IsPreUsedEmail";
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", Url, false);
    xmlHttp.send('jbjkb@kjbk');
    var xmldoc;
    xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
    xmldoc.loadXML(xmlHttp.responseXML.xml);
    if (xmldoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
         alert("DOM Not Loaded")
    }            
    return xmlHttp.responseXML.xml;
 }
```

Server side:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool IsPreUsedEmail(string sEmail) 
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the url to,

```
var Url = "http://localhost:52476/MyShul/Services/GetData.asmx/IsPreUsedEmail?sEmail=example@example.com";
```